# Issue retrieving session data on checkout.session.completed Stripe-Go

Tags: go, stripe-payments

My goal is after a customer completes a checkout session (using Stripe pre-built checkout) take the items that they ordered and save them to my MongoDB Database. The problem that I am encountering is that when I try and retrieve the CheckoutSession LineItems they are always nil.
Sorry if this question seems pretty poorly worded, I am new here.

Here is a snippet of the Webhook endpoint, I tried to omit all code that is not relevant including error handling.

```golang
payload, err := c.GetRawData()
event, err := webhook.ConstructEventWithOptions(payload, c.Request.Header.Get("Stripe-Signature"), webhookSecret, webhook.ConstructEventOptions{IgnoreAPIVersionMismatch: true})

switch (event.Type) {
case "checkout.session.completed":
    var session stripe.CheckoutSession
    err := json.Unmarshal(event.Data.Raw, &session)

    if session.LineItems == nil {
        // I always get here
    }
```

**Expectation:**
I would expect that I would be able to get an array of the items that they purchased, and it would have data like the Stripe PriceID, quantity, etc...

**Outcome:**
LineItems is always nil, despite the fact that there are always items included in the order, when I tried printing out the CheckoutSession itself there were a lot more nils.

**My diagnosis:**
I can't help but wonder if this has to do with the API version mismatch, you can see that when I construct the event I add the option to ignore the API version mismatch. Something I encountered was that the StripeCLI was apparently using an older version of the Stripe API, (I should note that I downloaded the latest official release today from the offical GitHub and am using that version 1.17.2). The CLI recommended I add that flag.
I also found it weird that on pkg.go.dev stripe-go lists the latest version as v70.15.0+incompatible and release on April 14th, 2020? And as a result running `go get -u github.com/stripe/stripe-go` gets you this version. But if I go to the stripe-go GitHub Repo it says the latest version is v75.6.0 and it recommends adding Go like this `go get -u github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v75`.
You are probably reading this thinking "wow this guys is dumb, has he never heard of LTS" but I thought I might mention this as it is the only thing I could think of.

**Note:**
I would also like to mention that I did have some issues with their Docs, they said to do this:

```golang
...
params := &stripe.CheckoutSessionParams{}
    params.AddExpand("line_items")

    // Retrieve the session. If you require line items in the response, you may include them by expanding line_items.
    sessionWithLineItems, _ := session.Get(session.ID, params)
    lineItems := sessionWithLineItems.LineItems
```

To get the line items but I got the error: `Unresolved reference 'Get'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69938982/2718163) mentions, the [line_items](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/line_items) of a Session are "expandable" and not included by default. This means that they are not included in the object when delivered in a webhook event.

You must make a separate request to either :

- retrieve the Checkout Session object and explicitly expand `line_items`, or
- retrieve the [listLineItems](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/line_items)

Also, stripe-go, stripe-dotnet and stripe-java are all pinned to a specific API versions (since they are strongly typed and every API change can break deserialization). You should make sure you [create your webhook endpoint with exact same API version](https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints/create#create_webhook_endpoint-api_version) that you're using in your code.

The Stripe CLI can only send/forward webhooks in your Stripe's account default API version, or the latest version : https://stripe.com/docs/cli/listen#listen-latest. You can see your account's default API version here : https://dashboard.stripe.com/developers.

Regarding the error `Unresolved reference 'Get'`, it's nearly impossible to tell what's going on based off the current info provided. It could be an IDE or project setup issue. You can try the answers listed in this question : [GoLand (JetBrains) shows error message "Unresolved Reference". But Code compiles and runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59556394/goland-jetbrains-shows-error-message-unresolved-reference-but-code-compiles)

Comment: I appreciate your help, the stripe-go docs named a variable session and it conflicted with the call to the session package.